# Why does a DAC affect the linearity of this sigma delta modulator?

Tags: adc

So according to these class slides the erros of the gain block and ADC make no problem because the integrator block before them minimizes those errors (lets say if i have an error of 10mV, divide that by 100 and i have a very small value)

[image]

[image]

But the DAC seems to make a huge problem.

[image]

"The output of the DAC is directly added (subtracted) from the input signal. This means that any error in the DAC output will be reflected directly in the input signal and it will not be affected by the integrator gain." But the blocks of gain and ADC come before the integrator so the signals that exit those blocks also will be reflected directly in the input signal. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The DAC is what gives you feedback (makes the process closed-loop). Any errors in the gain and ADC stages are driven to 0 by the feedback. Any errors in the feedback *itself* aren't corrected by anything.